# Does goroutine create a deep copy or shallow copy?

Tags: go, goroutine

```
var person struct {
    name string
    id   int
    phone int
}

func main () {
    var myTest person
    //construct the variable 
    ...


    go func() {
        fmt.Println(myTest.name)
    }()
}
```

Does the goroutine deep copy the variable "myTest" from main function?

If my goroutine like this:

```
go func() {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(myTest.name)
}
```

This goroutine sleep 10 seconds, so when the main function change the value of "myTest" during 10 seconds, what will goroutine do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no concept of "deep copy" in go, everything is passed by value.
**no your sample even is not a shallow copy** you passed a pointer (address of string):
if you change `myTest.name` in `main` function then you print it again after that   change you will see it will change, see this proving sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type person struct {
    name  string
    id    int
    phone int
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    myTest := person{"Alex", 22, 123}
    fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v %v\n", myTest.name, &myTest.name) // string : Alex 0xc042006740
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v %v\n", myTest.name, &myTest.name) // string : Alex 0xc042006740
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v %v\n", myTest.name, &myTest.name) // string : J 0xc042006740
        wg.Done()
    }()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    myTest.name = "J"
    wg.Wait()
}
```

first define `person struct` like this:

```
type person struct {
    name  string
    id    int
    phone int
}
```

second use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for goroutine to finish.

and about your main question, you can test it yourself like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type person struct {
    name  string
    id    int
    phone int
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    myTest := person{"Alex", 22, 123}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v\n", myTest.name) // string : Alex
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v\n", myTest.name) // string : J
        wg.Done()
    }()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    myTest.name = "J"
    wg.Wait()
}
```

so as you see in this sample the string `name` content change in the main function reflected to goroutine, so it is not a copy.
if you need copy call like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type person struct {
    name  string
    id    int
    phone int
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    myTest := person{"Alex", 22, 123}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(name string) {
        fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v\n", name) // string : Alex
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("%T : %[1]v\n", name) // string : Alex
        wg.Done()
    }(myTest.name)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    myTest.name = "J"
    wg.Wait()
}
```

and see: [Is it correct to ref a var inside golang func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487173/is-it-correct-to-ref-a-var-inside-golang-func/37491604#37491604)

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of "deep copy" in go, everything is passed by value.

In your instance, that's not a copy, you're referencing the variable directly, if you want a copy do something like:

```
myTest := myTest
time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
fmt.Println(myTest.name)
```